# UIBezierPath not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I try to draw a separator for slider, which must be at position of 1/3 of slider length. The slider body draws successfully, buy separator - not, it doesn't show.

Code is following

```
class RangeSliderTrackLayer:CALayer {
weak var rangeSlider:RangeSlider?

override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {

    if let slider = rangeSlider {
        let cornerRadius = bounds.height * 1 / 2.0
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor)
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath)
        CGContextFillPath(ctx)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor)
        let lowerValuePosition = CGFloat(40)
        let upperValuePosition = CGFloat(80)
        let rect = CGRect(x: lowerValuePosition, y: 0.0, width: upperValuePosition - lowerValuePosition, height: bounds.height)
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect)

        let separatorPath = UIBezierPath()
        var x = bounds.width / 3
        var y = bounds.height
        separatorPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x + 2, y: y))
        separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x + 2, y: 0))
        separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
        separatorPath.closePath()
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        separatorPath.stroke()
    }


}
```

}

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: First off, does your code even get into that bit of code?  `rangeSlider` could be nil at any time.  Are you sure that you are drawing that path into the correct context (do you know what the current context is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setFill()` but then then calling `stroke()`. Fill and stroke are two separate things. So, you either want:

1. Go ahead and set the fill color with `setFill()`, but then call `fill()` instead of `stroke()`:

   ```
   let separatorPath = UIBezierPath()
   var x = bounds.width / 3
   var y = bounds.height
   separatorPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
   separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x + 2, y: y))
   separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x + 2, y: 0))
   separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
   separatorPath.closePath()
   UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
   // separatorPath.stroke()
   separatorPath.fill()
   ```
2. Or call `stroke()` like you are not, but instead of calling `setFill()`, instead set `lineWidth` and call `setStroke()`:

   ```
   let separatorPath = UIBezierPath()
   var x = bounds.width / 3
   var y = bounds.height
   separatorPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
   separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x + 2, y: y))
   separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x + 2, y: 0))
   separatorPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
   separatorPath.closePath()
   // UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
   UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()
   separatorPath.lineWidth = 1
   separatorPath.stroke()
   ```